# UITextField setText resetting position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am setting the position of my `UITextField` when `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is fired like so

```
[chatTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(chatTextField.frame.origin.x, chatTextField.frame.origin.y - 250, chatTextField.frame.size.width, chatTextField.frame.size.height)];
```

[image]

However when I then call

```
[chatTextField setText: @""];
```

[image]

The position of the `UITextField` is set back to where it was in the beginning (under the keyboard). This also happens for the `UIWebView` also on the same view.
Why does it reset the positions? Am I setting the frame position in an incorrect way?

Comment: Use both UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, not just one, to detect the keyboard presence.

Answer (score 0):

You set the frame correct. you need to provide more code of your problem...

Comment: I am calling [chatTextField setText: @""] when return is pressed using textFieldShouldReturn that is what is causing the view to reset. It really has very little code to show, other than that.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
      [chatTextField setText: @""];

 return NO;
}
```

YOU need to return  **NO**

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it to no. However this has not fixed the issue the positions of both components is resetting still. Commenting out [chatTextField setText: @""]; stops this from happening. I'd also like to note hiding the keyboard puts them back to normal, which really they should stay the same.